# Magento 2 : How to create a dynamic menu in magento 2

Tags: magento2

guys, my question is how I create menu dynamic because I don't know how to create menu dynamically in Magento 2

Comment: Do you want to add category menu?

Comment: yes I am creating a category and add a page but I don't know how I add style and change category position in magento 2